# MVC 2 C# LINQ to SQL search with category

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a drop down list that is used to filter data from a table.  The drop down list has two items: with xx and without xx.

How do I construct a L2S query to filter a table?

An example SQL call is `SELECT * FROM ProductionTasks WHERE Designation like '% xx %'`

There is a controller named TaskDatabaseController.cs and the database with the ProductionTasks table is named MyDatabase.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what is being asked here. You will probably have to clarify your question, otherwise I believe it will be close pretty soon.

Comment: Also, you might wish to address the numerous spelling and grammatical mistakes.

Comment: ProductionTasks.Where(t => t.Designation.Contains("xx")); ?

Comment: @Chris Lively:   Well done for stitching a shirt onto that button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you have asked here.
If you need the `linq` query for above sql statement

```
var db = new YourDataContext();
var task = from ptask in db.ProductionTasks 
           where ptask.Designation.Contains("xx")
           select ptask;
```